# moment does not set to Time type

Tags: html, angular, timepicker

The problem is bizarre since it happens only to users abroad, although they are using chrome like me and in my country(Israel) I don't face the issue.

I'm using Angular 2. 
I assign time to FormControl and bind the formControlName to type="time". The time does not set and I get an empty field.

Questions: 
1. How can I reproduce it? considering it does not reproduce in my country.
2. If someone can point to the problem it will be fantastic.

```
<div (click)="startTimeInput.click()" class="time-div">
        <mat-form-field fxFlex class="time">
          <input matInput type="time" (TimeChanged)="changeTime($event)" #startTimeInput placeholder="{{'START TIME' | translate}}" formControlName="startTime" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-icon class="time-picker-button">access_time</mat-icon>
      </div>
```

```
 zone.run(() => {
      if (this.unpack(this.data)) {
        this.ShiftForm = new FormGroup({
          role: new FormControl(this.role ? this.role : this.settings ? this.settings.role : this.roleNames[1], Validators.required),
          capacity: new FormControl(this.capacity ? this.capacity : this.settings ? this.settings.capacity : 1, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/)]),
          startDate: new FormControl(moment(this.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/)]),
          startTime: new FormControl(this.startTime, Validators.required),
          endDate: new FormControl(moment(this.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/[0-9]/)]),
          endTime: new FormControl(this.endTime, Validators.required),
          labels: new FormControl(this.labels ? this.labels : this.settings ? this.settings.labels : []),
          forceAssign: new FormControl(this.forceAssignees ? this.forceAssignees : this.membersListedInShift ? this.membersListedInShift : [])
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Actual: 
time is empty

Expected: 
time is set

Comment: How are you setting `this.startTime`? Moment parses by default to local time, can you try `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`?

Comment: Local is good. I parse to utc only when sending to backend. The startTime returns from fullcalendar view.